# Where Jenkins stores SVN credentials

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jenkins

Started to play around with Jenkins. Created new job and entered SVN repository URL. Pressed build and jenkins successfully checked-out my repository. My repository has not got anonymous access. No clue, how Jenkins managed to checked-out repository.

Running on Windows XP + Tomcat6 + Jenkins war file.

Probably Jenkins managed to read password from system properties ? Right now trying to find this configuration file, where it store password-s or settings

**UPDATE**

Not sure, but looks like, Jenkins read SVN credentials from tortoise svn cache. When i cleaned  cache, can't access repository anymore from Jenkins

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Indeed, it takes it from Subversion cache. At least, right now I know, that it's not good idea, to save passwords

Subversion will look in the `$HOME/.subversion` file for credentials, but it also stores the password under each job in a file called `subversion.credentials`.

Usually, your Jenkins machine isn't accessible to mere mortals and you can make the Jenkins `$HOME` directory owned by another user. This way, you can use your OS's security features to prevent people from peeking in at your Jenkins credentials.

Another possibility is to make the Subversion checkout user for Jenkins a read-only user. That will allow Jenkins to checkout the code, but if someone snags the Jenkins Subversion account, they won't be able to make changes.

If you also use Jenkins to tag your Subversion builds, you can use a [pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) to allow Jenkins to create a tag, but not be able to do anything else.

That should ease your security concerns. If you think about it, Jenkins has to be able to store its subversion account and password, or else it won't be able to automatically checkout the code for a build.

Answer (score 4):

credentials.xml, in default, it's under ~/.jenkins/

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, with a Jenkins restart afterwards, then adding my svn credentials back in

Comment: This is the place!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it takes it from Subversion cache. At least, right now I know, that it's not good idea, to save passwords

Answer (score 0):

I found easiest way to update the password .

Generally its a secured http connection i mean https. just change it to http then immediately Jenkins will prompt you to update the svn details where you can update the credentials and url .[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins stores the svn credentials in the .jenkins/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml, delete old userName and password entries and keep entries blank and save the file.
Later restart the jenkins and go the job configuration and Repository URL, Jenkins will prompt to enter new svn credentials.
-Praveen